# Outlook 2010 compatibility with Exchange Online

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

Exchange 2019 on premise requires Outlook 2013 and newer:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019

Will Office365 Exchange Online work with Outlook 2010 SP2 until end of extended support end date of Oct 13, 2020?

Answer (score 2):

According to this official document:

"For information about which Outlook clients are supported by Exchange 2016 and Exchange Online, see "Supported clients" in Exchange 2016 system requirements." 
And from the linked article mentioned above, the supported clients for Exchange Online and Exchange 2016 are as follows:

•   Outlook 2016

•   Outlook 2013

•   Outlook 2010 SP2 and updates KB2956191 and KB2965295

•   Outlook for Mac for Office 365

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b825fa10-e07b-4955-b02b-97726f6867b1/office-2010-support-for-exchange-online-mailboxes?forum=outlook

In addition, from Exchange 2019, Exchange On-premises is designed not as the same as Exchange Online. So they will be a little different.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange Online supports the same Outlook client versions as Exchange Server 2016.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#clients

Comment: I just checked the link. Where does it say that Exchange Online supports the same Outlook client versions as Exchange 2016?

Comment: That link shows which clients are supported by on premises versions of Exchange Server. Exchange Online supports the same clients that Exchange Server 2016 does, therefore that link shows you which clients are supported by Exchange Online by virtue of showing you which clients are supported by Exchange Server 2016.